# Launching vokoscreen from CMD doesn't have access to codecs

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe, desktop-application, desktop-recording

I am required to launch  programatically vokoscreen from CMD (or any other programatical strategy).
I am using the following command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\vokoscreenNG\vokoscreenNG.exe" && exit

However, **when launched from command line all the codecs are unavailable to the app**,
condemning its proper execution. When I launch it manually, all codecs are normally available.

[image: No codec access]

What can I do to launch it programatically (scripts, macro, batch files...) and allow proper access to the codecs.

Comment: We're not here to provide you with a how to perform a task service, we're here to helpp you to fix a single, specific, and reproducible issue with your submitted code. Where is that code, and its explanatory and debugging inforamtion?

Comment: So when you launch it manually what are the properties of the icon you double clicked on with your mouse.  I would bet there is a start in folder set and maybe other parameters being passed to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch VokoScreen with the working directory being the VokoScreen install folder.

```
start "VokoScreen" /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\vokoscreenNG" "vokoscreenNG.exe"
```

OR

```
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\vokoscreenNG"
"vokoscreenNG.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, in the end I was able to do it using Blueprism and spying the application with External, 32 bit mode. This makes the object run in a separate process, and recover access to most codecs (but not all). But the main cause of this issue remains unknown and was unable to work from cmd.